# How to set view width to be a percent of parent width - some space for margins in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I want to create a layout as on the picture below:

[image]

So each button takes 50% of (parent width - space for margins)

If I set `layout_constraintWidth_percent` to 0.5 it doesn't work. I can achieve this using `LinearLayout` and weight, but how to do it with `ConstraintLayout`?

Here is the layout I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/other_options"
      style="?tertiaryButtonStyle"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="@dimen/half_pad"
      android:text="@string/report_suicide_other_options_action"
      app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/yes"
      style="?primaryButtonStyle"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="@dimen/half_pad"
      android:text="@string/action_yes"
      app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/other_options"
      />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add:

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/yes"
```

to the `Button` with id `other_options`

and you can remove

```
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
```

from both buttons.